# jQuery checkbox validation

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I'm using the jQuery code below to validate a form. Now it all works great but I would like for the checkbox validation to use the `.validator` rather than its current `alert`, but when I add `required="required"` to the checkbox input boxes, I get messages for all of the checkboxes, whereas I only need one.

```
$("#request-form").validator({
    message: '<div><em/></div>',
    position: 'top left',
    offset: [3, 40]
});

$("#see").overlay({mask: '#999', fixed: false}).bind("onBeforeClose", function(e) {
    $(".error").hide();
});

$('#request-form').submit(function(){
    if(!$('#request-form input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
        alert("Please check at least one.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance. S

Comment: This is a bit out of topic, but don't forget that on the server side you *still* have to test the whole result, because it may not have been filtered and you still may get unpredictable things in your request (i.e. request sent by hackers ).

Comment: I am relatively new to jQuery and selectorsm, but isn't there a way to define more specific jQuery selector for a particular checkbox only instead of all checkboxes in the form? Hope I am not pushing you in the wrong track.

Comment: What plugin are you using for this?  It isn't the [standard validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)...

Comment: It's built into jquery tools http://flowplayer.org/tools/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code that will work with the [JQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). I'm not sure if this will work with what you're using because I've never heard of it.

```
$("#request-form").validate({
    rules: {
        checkbox: { 
        required: 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked',
        minlength: $('input[type="checkbox"]').length()
        }
    },
    messages: {
        checkbox: "Please check at least one.",
    }
});
```

HTH

Comment: replaced link , thoank you