# jquery validation multiple checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have some check boxes

```
<input type="check" name="chkOption" id="one" />One
<input type="check" name="chkOption" id="two" />two
<input type="check" name="chkOption" id="three" />three
<input type="check" name="chkOption" id="four" />four
```

is it possible to validate "required" any one of this check box using "jquery.validate" script,

Comment: Take a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932723/jquery-checkbox-validation

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535187/jquery-validate-form-with-multiple-checkboxes-at-least-one-must-be-checked

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("check", function(value, elem, param) {
    if($(".roles:checkbox:checked").length > 0){
       return true;
   }else {
       return false;
   }
},"You must select at least one!");​
```