# jquery validate - clicking "submit" checks a checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a script that validates a form (using [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)) and then submits data. It's currently working great, but now I need to add a checkbox and I'm not clear on how to submit the value using jquery/ajax. Do I need to include something like `$('#checkBox').attr('checked');`? And if so, how do I pass that on to ajax?

Also, when I click "submit", without having completed the form, the checkbox auto-checks itself. Why is this happening?

jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formid").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required:   true,
                email:      true
            },
            mobile: {
                required:   true,
                minlength:  10
            },
            news: {
                required:   false,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name:   "Please enter your name",
            email:  "Please enter a valid email address",
            mobile: "Please enter your mobile number"
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
                var name        = $('#name').attr('value');
                var email       = $('#email').attr('value'); 
                var mobile      = $('#mobile').attr('value');
                var news        = $('#news').attr('value');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: $("#formid").serialize(),
                    success: function(){
                        $('form#formid').hide();
                        $('div.success').fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

form:

```
<form id="formid" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required"  />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="required" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" class="required" />
        </div>
        <label for="news"><p>Please don&rsquo;t send me ongoing news</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="news" name="news" value="No" />

    <label for="submit1" id="submit"><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <input id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unclosed `label` tag that the browser is extending to encompass both the `checkbox` and the `submit` button.

```
<label for="news">
    <p>Please don&rsquo;t send me ongoing news</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="news" name="news" value="No" />
<!-- should close news label here -->    
<label for="submit1" id="submit">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <input id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</label>
```

This is causing both the `checkbox` and `submit` to act as if they were clicked when either of them is clicked.

Fixing your markup should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has previously been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933266/214747). The link to [this demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) should also help.

Please note, jquery serialize will only include the checkbox value if it is checked.